# Editor de blogs en React. Almacenamiento en Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Estoy haciendo una página en la que los usuarios pueden crear blogs. Actualmente el contenido de los blogs lo recibo como texto plano a través de un **textarea**, sin embargo, necesito hacer uso de un Rich text editor que me permita guardar el contenido en el formato de Firebase Realtime Database, y poder consultar dicho contenido para mostrarlo con el formato con el que se editó. El código del componente para crear artículos es el siguiente:

```
import { mainTopics } from "./topics.js";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
   title: "",
   date: "",
   topic: "",
   article: "",
   error: null,
};

class PostForm extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         ...INITIAL_STATE,
      };

      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   }

   handleSubmit(event) {
      this.props.onSubmit(
         event,
         this.props.postInfo
            ? {
                 postId: this.props.postInfo.id,
                 title: this.state.title,
                 date: this.state.date,
                 topic: this.state.topic,
                 article: this.state.article,
              }
            : {}
      );
   }

   handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({
         [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      });

      this.props.onChange(event);
   }

   render() {
      const { title, date, topic, article, error } = this.state;

      const isInvalid =
         title === "" ||
         article === "" ||
         topic === "" ||
         topic === "-" ||
         date === "";

      return (
         <div className="form-container">
            <form className="post-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               <input
                  className="new-post-input"
                  name="title"
                  value={title}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Title"
               />
               <input
                  className="new-post-input"
                  name="date"
                  value={date}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  type="date"
                  placeholder="Date of creation"
               />
               <section>
                  <label htmlFor="topic">Select the topic of your text: </label>
                  <select
                     name="topic"
                     value={topic}
                     onChange={this.handleChange}
                  >
                     {mainTopics.map((topic, index) => (
                        <option key={index} value={topic}>
                           {topic}
                        </option>
                     ))}
                  </select>
               </section>


               <textarea
                  className="article-text-area"
                  name="article"
                  value={article}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  placeholder="This is the body of your post"
               />
               <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit">
                  Post it
               </button>

               {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
            </form>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Cuando el usuario hace click en submit, el siguiente código se ejecuta:

```
handleSubmit(event, object) {
      const { title, date, topic, article } = this.state;

      const newPublication = {
         title,
         date,
         topic,
         article,
      };

      const { email, uid } = this.props.firebase.auth.currentUser;

      this.props.firebase.userPosts(uid).push(newPublication);
      let postKey;

      this.props.firebase
         .userPosts(uid)
         .limitToLast(1)
         .on("child_added", snapshot => {
            postKey = snapshot.key;
         });

      const keyEmail = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));

      this.props.firebase.setByTopic(topic, `${keyEmail}${postKey}`, {
         email,
         ...newPublication,
      });

      this.setState({ editing: false });

      this.handleDatabaseUpdate(false);
      event.preventDefault();
   }
```

Esto es lo que se guarda en firebase

[image]

Y así es como se ve una publicación en la sección de publicaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jona. 
Prueba con estos editores enriquecidos:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html
o
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/

Estos te ahorran tiempo :)

En firebase puedes guardar html. Almacena la data entregada por los componente en una variable de tipo string. Y cuando quieras mostrarla, la recuperas y se la pasas a los mismos, ellos se encangaran de convertirlo a texto enriquecido listo para editarse.
DEMO:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html

Comment: ¡Gracias Carlos!, probaré a ver cómo me va.